# How to unlock a physical device via XCUITest or xcrun?

Tags: swift, xctest, xcuitest

I'm attempting to write an UI test for lock/unlock device behavior for my app.
Now I'm managing to lock the screen and go to enter password page, here's my code:

```
func testLockScreen() {
    XCUIDevice.shared.perform(NSSelectorFromString("pressLockButton"))
    sleep(1)
    XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)
    sleep(1)
    XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)
    sleep(1)
    //need to press pasword buttons to unlock the device
  }
```

Not sure how to implement this part, I've tried to use the Record UI Test feature, but it's a UIApplication object, not XCUIDevice.

Any suggestion would be great, thanks!

Comment: I don't think you're able to do that, even if you can do it with some private APIs somehow, your app will be rejected if you have a plan to upload it to AppStore.